# Free memory of Object assigned to multiple StringList

Tags: delphi, memory, delphi-7

I have an object which is assigned to multiple `TStringList` objects.

Releasing memory for first `TStringList` works fine.
But when i call Object.Free for the second `TStringList`, it results in Access Violation.

This is how the object is assigned to the 2 `TStringList`

```
     SL1.AddObject(S, Person);
     if (Sl2<> nil) and (Var1 <> '')
       then Sl2.AddObject(Var1,TObject(Person));
```

This is how memory is released.

**SL1**

Method:**ReleaseSL1**

```
For J := SL1.Count - 1 downto 0  do
  begin
     if (SL1.Objects[J]) <> nil then
       begin
         PersonObj:= TPerson(SL1.Objects[J]);
         PersonObj.Free;
         SL1.Objects[J] := nil;
       end;
  end;
```

**SL2**

Method:**ReleaseSL2**

```
  for I := 0 to SL2.Count-1 do
    if SL2.Objects[I] <> nil then
      begin
        PersonObj := TPerson(SL2.Objects[I]);
        PersonObj .Free;
        SL2.Objects[I] := nil;
      end;
  SL2.Clear;
```

Here, when PersonObj.Free is executed in method ReleaseSL2, it results in Access Violation

Is there any way, apart from restructuring of code, that I can avoid this Access Violation?

Note: There are many more objects assigned to both SL1 and SL2 and the 2 `TStringList` objects are not identical

Comment: What is your question? - I'm sure you're not asking about why you cannot `free` a single object more than once...

Comment: The question is "Why does it result in to Access Violation".
If it is already freed for SL1 then SL2.Objects[I] <> nil should return true and AV will be avoided.If it is not freed, it should not result into AV

Comment: No, `SL2` cannot 'know' that the object was already freed elsewhere. Why do you think that `SL1.Objects[J] := nil;` would change anything inside `SL2`? It does not.

Comment: "If it is already freed for SL1 then SL2.Objects[I] <> nil should return true" -- These two statements are unrelated: What `SL2.Objects[I] <> nil` results in is completely independent from what happened for `SL1`.

Comment: Also, *don't* use a `TStringList` for objects that are not strings! Use `TObjectList` instead.

Comment: Well if releasing SL1 would not change anything inside SL2, then why the Access Violation when releasing SL2?

Comment: Because you released the objects *inside* `SL1`. Changing these objects does *not* change `SL2`; it only changes the *objects* `SL2` holds references to.

Comment: Well, this is a legacy code. Restructuring the code is obviously a solution, but i would prefer a solution with minimum of change. I would go for restructuring as the last option

Comment: Ok, so is there anyway(apart from restructuring the code) i can avoid AV when releasing SL2?

Answer (score 1):

You're freeing the object and only nilling one of the two references to that object (the one in SL1).

Consider the following test application:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TTest = class(TObject);

var
  A, B: TTest;

begin
  A := TTest.Create;
  B := A;
  WriteLn(Format('Assigned A: %s  B: %s',
         [BoolToStr(Assigned(A), True), BoolToStr(Assigned(B), True)]));

  FreeAndNil(A);
  WriteLn(Format('Assigned A: %s  B: %s',
         [BoolToStr(Assigned(A), True), BoolToStr(Assigned(B), True)]));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The output it produces:

```
Assigned A: True  B: True
Assigned A: False  B: True
```

Note that, even though you've called `FreeAndNil` on `A`, it doesn't automagically set the value of `B` to nil as well. The compiler has no way of knowing that you're finished with the other reference.

The solution to your particular issue is simple: when freeing the object in `SL1`, see if it exists in `SL2` and nil it at the same time. (You also don't need the local variable `PersonObj`. If you've properly overridden the inherited methods, the proper `Free` will be called for you.)

```
var
  RefIdx: Integer;

For J := SL1.Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  if SL1.Objects[J] <> nil then
  begin
    RefIdx := SL2.IndexOfObject(SL1.Objects[J]);
    if RefIdx > -1 then
      SL2.Objects[RefIdx] := nil;

    SL1.Objects[J].Free;
    SL1.Objects[J] := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You explanation is clear. Though, it does not answer my question. In above case, how do i clear B? For me FreeAndNil(SL2.Objects[I]) results into AV.

Or you are saying that there is no way that you can Free `B` in above case?

Comment: "You're freeing only one instance of the object reference" - This reads a little confusing, because you don't "free" a reference. He's freeing the *object* and discarding/overwriting/nilling *one* of the two+ references to that object.

Comment: @HannoBinder: You're right; the phrasing was confusing. Corrected as you suggest. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Maulik: All that is needed is `B := nil;` - as the object has already been freed, you don't need to do so again. The object (and the memory allocated for it) has already been freed when you `FreeAndNil(A);`.

Comment: `<Shudder>`. If there is a need for `FreeAndNil`, there is clearly something wrong with the entire setup.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you don't try to `free` an object tiwce, you can use somehing like this:

```
For J := SL1.Count - 1 downto 0  do
  begin
     if (SL1.Objects[J]) <> nil then
       begin
         PersonObj:= TPerson(SL1.Objects[J]);

         // Make sure this object is not kept in SL2 any more:
         SL2.remove(PersonObj);

         PersonObj.Free;
         SL1.Objects[J] := nil;
       end;
  end;



  for I := 0 to SL2.Count-1 do
    if SL2.Objects[I] <> nil then
      begin
        PersonObj := TPerson(SL2.Objects[I]);
        PersonObj .Free;

        // Make sure this object is not kept in SL1 any more:
        SL1.remove(PersonObj);

        SL2.Objects[I] := nil;
      end;
  SL2.Clear;
```

One note: You only need to remove the object from the other list if that list is not already cleared.

Comment: I like this solution. :) I will try it out. Thnx.

Comment: `TStringList` does not have a `Remove()` method.  You might be thinking of `TList`. Instead, you would have to use the `IndexOfObject()` and `Delete()` methods: `Idx := SL2.IndexOfObject(PersonObj); if Idx <> -1 then SL2.Delete(Idx);`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way, apart from restructuring of code, that I can avoid this Access Violation?

No.  A restructure is required.  You need to clearly define who **owns** the `TPerson` objects, and who merely **refers** to them.  In your example, `SL1` can **own** the objects and SL2 should **refer** to them.  Free the objects only from the list that **owns** them, and remove any references from the list that **refers** to them without freeing them again.

```
SL1.AddObject(S, Person); // <--assumed ownership
if (Sl2 <> nil) and (Var1 <> '') then
  Sl2.AddObject(Var1, Person); // <-- reference only
```

```
For J := SL1.Count - 1 downto 0  do
begin
  if (SL1.Objects[J]) <> nil then
  begin
    TPerson(SL1.Objects[J]).Free;
    SL1.Objects[J] := nil;
  end;
end;

//...

SL2.Clear;
```

Otherwise, you need to use a third list that **owns** the objects, and then have both SL1 and SL2 merely **refer** to them:

```
Objects.Add(Person); // <-- asssumed ownership
SL1.AddObject(S, Person); // <-- reference only
if (Sl2 <> nil) and (Var1 <> '') then
  Sl2.AddObject(Var1, Person); // <-- reference only
```

```
For J := SL1.Count - 1 downto 0  do
  SL1.Objects[J] := nil;

//...

SL2.Clear;

//...

For J := 0 to Objects.Count - 1 do
  TPerson(Objects[J]).Free;
Objects.Clear;
```

If you use a `TObjectList` or `TObjectList<TPerson>` for the third list, you can set their `OwnsObjects` property to True to auto-manage the lifetime of the `TPerson` objects for you.

FYI, on modern Delphi versions, `TStringList` also has an `OwnsObjects` property, but I would not suggest using it in this situation.

Comment: Of course, all this means that the owning list must outlive any referring lists, otherwise, the referrering lists might refer to a freed object.